# Удаление из файла

Tags: файлы, хеширование, c++

Помогите пожалуйста доделать программку. Основа работает как надо. Я только не могу сделать чтобы удаление из файла происходило по таб номеру (функция del). Удаляет, но пока не из файла.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 103

struct info
    {
     int tab;
     char fam[20];
     float oklad;
     info()
     {
      tab=0; oklad=0;
     }
    }; info T[N];

int hesh(int key){ return key % N;}
void forms(char fl[]);//formiruet hesh tabl T iz faila fl
void output();//vivod mas T na ekran
int search(int p);//funkc vozvrash index zapisi s tab nomerom=p ili -1
void add (info g);//dobavl zapic g v tabl T
void del (info g);//udalenie
void record();

void main()
    {
     int z,k,s;
     info m,n;
     clrscr();
     forms("1.txt");
     cout<<endl;
     output();
     cout<<"Vvedidet tab fam oklad novogo sotr:"<<endl;
     cout<<"Tab nom:";
     while (cin>>m.tab)
        {
         cout<<"Familiya:"; cin>>m.fam;
         cout<<"Oklad:"; cin>>m.oklad;
         int i=search(m.tab);
         if (i!=-1)
            {
             cout<<"3anogo"<<endl;
             T[i]=m;
            }
            else {add(m); break;}
        }
     output();
     for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
         {
          cout<<"\n\nVvedite tab nom poiska:";
          cin>>z;
          k=search(z);
          if (k==-1) cout<<"Ne naiden"; else
            cout<<T[k].tab<<'\t'<<T[k].fam<<'\t'<<T[k].oklad<<'\n';
         }
     cout<<endl<<"Vvedidet tab nomer del:"<<endl;
     cin>>n.tab;
     del(n);
     record();
     output();
     getch();
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void add (info g)
    {
     int j=0;
     int i=hesh(g.tab);
     while (T[i].tab!=0 && j<N)
        {
         i=hesh(i+1);
         j++;
        }
     if (j==N){ cout<<"Tabl perepolnena";getch(); exit (0);}
        else T[i]=g;
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void forms(char fl[])
    {
     ifstream F(fl);
     info x;
     while (F>>x.tab>>x.fam>>x.oklad)
     add(x);
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void output()
      {
       cout<<"index tab fam oklad   "<<endl;
       for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        if (T[i].tab!=0)
            cout<<i<<'\t'<<T[i].tab<<'\t'<<T[i].fam<<'\t'<<T[i].oklad<<'\n';
      }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int search (int p)
      {
       int j=0, i=hesh(p);
       while (j++<N && T[i].tab)
        {
         if (T[i].tab==p)
            return i;
         i=hesh(i+1);
        }
       return -1;
      }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void del (info g)
      {
       int i=hesh(g.tab);
       if (search) T[i].tab=NULL;
      }

void record()
      {
       ofstream fl("1.txt");
       for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        if (T[i].tab!=0)
            fl<<T[i].tab<<"\t"<<T[i].fam<<"\t"<<T[i].oklad<<endl;
      }
```

Спасибо большое avp, вот рабочий код. Мне было тяжело конечно.

Comment: @Fint, если прямо следовать логике в main (той, что сейчас), то все просто.

Смотрите, в forms() Вы почли файл в T[]. Затем что-то добавили в нее. Потом прочли номер, вызвали `del()` и удалили запись из T[].

Я предлагаю выбросить из программы запись в 1.txt, как она сделана сейчас. А вместо этого после `del()` вызвать функцию, аналогичную `output()`, которая запишет (перепишет заново) содержимое T[] в 1.txt

Вот и все.

Comment: Понятно что потребуется ещё одна функция простая для перезаписи типа
ofstream f("1.txt");
f<<T[i].tab<<T[i].fam<<T[i].oklad
примерно. А вот не понял откуда выбросить из программы запись в 1.txt. Вы имели ввиду наверно строчку ofstream f("1.txt",ios::app); и следующую?

Comment: Вот это

     ofstream f("1.txt",ios::app);
     f<<m.tab<<'\t'<<m.fam<<'\t'<<'\t'<<m.oklad<<endl;

и выбрасывайте.